# How does sas allocate memory for data types

Tags: sas

Say if I am creating a dataset with 3 Observations and 2 variables i.e name and id.
If out of the 3 observations only 1 observation requires 25 characters .

```
DATASET practice;
INPUT Name  $25. Id;
DATALINES;
a 20        *1st observation;
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy 10     *2nd observation;
abc 15;      *3rd observation
run;
```

Now my question is will sas allocate 25 characters for all the 3 observations or will it act like varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With default options, particularly `COMPRESS=NO`, SAS will allocate 25 bytes for the character, and pad the unused bytes with spaces ('20'x).  That is important not only for storage, but also for character comparisons; while most comparisons ignore trailing spaces, sometimes that's not true and trailing spaces will need to be trimmed explicitly.

However, if you use `OPTION COMPRESS=YES` or `OPTION COMPRESS=CHAR`, it will compress the field in datasets that are written out such that it acts more like `varchar` (it will not take up very much additional space for wasted columns).  The spaces are still technically present and may need to be considered in programs, but they do not require a full byte's storage.